# Por qué no muestra los input del formulario con Angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Acabo de empezar, he visto varias páginas pero a la hora de la verdad tengo :

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('miControlador',[ '$scope', function($scope) {
       
  $scope.nombrar= function() {
   alert($scope.nombre.n1);
  };
    
  $scope.alertar=function(){
   alert('ey'); 
  };
    
    
  $scope.cambiar = function() {
   alert($scope.nombre);
  };
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="myApp">
<div ng-controller="miControlador"> 
  <input type='text' ngModel='nombre.n1'    value=''>
  <input type='text' ngModel='nombre.n2'    value=''>
  <input type='text' ngModel='nombre.n3'   value=''>
  <button ng-click="cambiar()" >mostrar todo</button>
  <button ng-click="nombrar()" >ver primero</button>
  <button ng-click="alertar()" >alertar</button>
</div>
</body>
```

Sólo muestra el alert, pero cuando quiero coger los datos me sale "undefined"

Comment: Pregunta totalmente *offtopic* ¿acabas de empezar con AngularJS? ¿Es por necesidades del trabajo (mantener una aplicación ya existente o por interés propio? Me extraña que alguien empiece con [tag:angularJS] y no [tag:Angular]

Comment: acabo de empezar, he visto varias páginas pero a la hora de la verdad tengo , tengo que aprenderlo por necesidad pero sin ayuda.

Comment: por requerimiento debe ser angularjs (version 1.x)? no puede ser angular (versiones  2 en adelante)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El error que te marca es que no puede leer el atributo `n1` de una variable no definida, así que simplemente definamos la variable `nombre`.

Con respecto a por qué no te muestra los valores en los input es porque se hace de otra forma: debes llamar a la variable con llaves dobles y, por si quieres usar `ng-model`,  te muestro un ejemplo sobre eso (lo tenías mal escrito y lo usabas asignando el `value`, que no es correcto), analiza el código siguiente

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('miControlador',[ '$scope', function($scope) {

  $scope.nombre = {n1: 'Nombre1', n2: 'Nombre2', n3: 'Nombre3'};

  $scope.nombrar= function() {
   alert($scope.nombre.n1);
  };
    
  $scope.alertar=function(){
   alert('ey'); 
  };
    
    
  $scope.cambiar = function() {
   alert($scope.nombre);
  };
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="myApp">
<div ng-controller="miControlador"> 
  <label>Inputs que se les asigna como valor una variable del $scope.nombre</label><br/>
  <input type='text' value='{{nombre.n1}}'>
  <input type='text' value='{{nombre.n2}}' >
  <input type='text' value='{{nombre.n3}}' >
  <br/>
  <label>Input que utiliza como <b>modelo</b> la variable $scope.nombre.n1 lo que hara que al cambiarla te cambie el input que utiliza n1 como valor (y te lo cambiará de manera global)</label><br/>
  <input type='text' ng-model='nombre.n1'>
  <br/>
  <button ng-click="cambiar()" >Cambiar</button>
  <button ng-click="nombrar()" >ver</button>
  <button ng-click="alertar()" >alertar</button>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: pero eso solo muestra 'Nombre1' Yo quiero que muestre lo del input,cámbialo por otro valor y verás que siempre muestra Nombre1 y al darle a mostrar todo es object object

Comment: eso se hace con `ng-model` tu simplemente lo tenías mal escrito y asignabas `value` que no es correcto, revisa el ejemplo ahora veras que tengo un input al que solo le pongo la variable n1 de nombre mientras que tengo otro input que tiene como modelo la variable n1 de nombre, al cambiar el segundo input te cambiara el primero de manera automatica